# Reconnecting from Airplane Mode with MQTT Android Service

Tags: java, android, service, mqtt

I am implementing the Dale Lane MQTT Android Service Example found here http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599, the example is working pretty well for my specific purpose, but I am dealing with 1 issue that I cannot seem to resolve.

After testing rather extensively, I have found that the service does not reconnect after the phone has completely lost connection. For example, if the phone is placed in Airplane Mode and then taken out of Airplane mode, the service will continue to try to connectToBroker() but will never connect.

The application connects properly if I were to press the "connect" button on the main screen which starts the service with given host/topic parameters.

**How can I resolve this issue? The application has no issue re-connecting from Wifi-Network, vice-versa.**

```
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628): ping failed - MQTT exception
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628): com.ibm.mqtt.MqttNotConnectedException
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at com.ibm.mqtt.Mqtt.writePacket(Unknown Source)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at com.ibm.mqtt.Mqtt.pingOut(Unknown Source)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttClient.ping(Unknown Source)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at com.limosys.limosystestmqtt.MQTTService$PingSender.onReceive(MQTTService.java:919)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:778)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
02-16 12:19:39.348: E/mqtt(23628):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the stacktrace of the exception that is thrown if the ping fails, the application continues to try and connect every 10 seconds based on a given keepAliveSecond value.

**CONNECTIONLOST**

```
/*
   * callback - method called when we no longer have a connection to the message broker server
   */
  public void connectionLost() throws Exception {
    // we protect against the phone switching off while we're doing this
    // by requesting a wake lock - we request the minimum possible wake
    // lock - just enough to keep the CPU running until we've finished
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MQTT");
    wl.acquire();


    //
    // have we lost our data connection?
    //

    if (isOnline() == false) {
      Log.e("CONNECTION LOST", "LOST CONNECTION");
      connectionStatus = MQTTConnectionStatus.NOTCONNECTED_WAITINGFORINTERNET;

      // inform the app that we are not connected any more
      broadcastServiceStatus("Connection lost - no network connection");

      //
      // inform the user (for times when the Activity UI isn't running)
      // that we are no longer able to receive messages
      notifyUser("Connection lost - no network connection", "MQTT",
          "Connection lost - no network connection");

      //
      // wait until the phone has a network connection again, when we
      // the network connection receiver will fire, and attempt another
      // connection to the broker
    } else {
      //
      // we are still online
      // the most likely reason for this connectionLost is that we've
      // switched from wifi to cell, or vice versa
      // so we try to reconnect immediately
      //

      connectionStatus = MQTTConnectionStatus.NOTCONNECTED_UNKNOWNREASON;

      // inform the app that we are not connected any more, and are
      // attempting to reconnect
      broadcastServiceStatus("Connection lost - reconnecting...");

      // try to reconnect
      if (connectToBroker()) {
        subscribeToTopic(topicName);
      }
    }

    // we're finished - if the phone is switched off, it's okay for the CPU
    // to sleep now
    wl.release();
  }
```

**CONNECT TO BROKER**
This code is called several times after a service is available (ie, exiting airplane mode and connecting to 4G/Wifi)

```
 /*
   * (Re-)connect to the message broker
   */
  private boolean connectToBroker() {
    try {
      // try to connect
      Log.e("CONNECTTOBROKER", "TRYING TO CONNECT");
      Log.e("SERVICE HOST - CONNECT TO BROKER", "" + brokerHostName);
      Log.e("SERVICE TOPIC - CONNECT TO BROKER", "" + topicName);

      mqttClient.connect(generateClientId(), cleanStart, keepAliveSeconds);

      //
      // inform the app that the app has successfully connected
      broadcastServiceStatus("Connected");

      // we are connected
      connectionStatus = MQTTConnectionStatus.CONNECTED;

      // we need to wake up the phone's CPU frequently enough so that the
      // keep alive messages can be sent
      // we schedule the first one of these now
      scheduleNextPing();


      return true;
    } catch (MqttException e) {
      // something went wrong!

      connectionStatus = MQTTConnectionStatus.NOTCONNECTED_UNKNOWNREASON;

      //
      // inform the app that we failed to connect so that it can update
      // the UI accordingly
      broadcastServiceStatus("Unable to connect");

      //
      // inform the user (for times when the Activity UI isn't running)
      // that we failed to connect
      notifyUser("Unable to connect", "MQTT", "Unable to connect - will retry later");

      // if something has failed, we wait for one keep-alive period before
      // trying again
      // in a real implementation, you would probably want to keep count
      // of how many times you attempt this, and stop trying after a
      // certain number, or length of time - rather than keep trying
      // forever.
      // a failure is often an intermittent network issue, however, so
      // some limited retry is a good idea
      scheduleNextPing();

      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Download the latest android service jar(1.02) and java client(1.02) from paho.
Latest Android service jars have the fix for this issue. It takes care for reconnecting once the network connection is back.

add this inside onResume() of the Activity

```
mqttclient.registerResources(this);
```

and this inside onDestroy() of the same Activity

```
mqttclient.unregisterResources();
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... solved a long onging issue for me :D

Comment: glad it helped. After debugging a little bit more on this, found out that this only works if you have set clean session to false. And service wont restart if connection is lost by some issue from server end. Above answer works well when network gets disconnected and comes back.

Comment: @kdoteu I am interested in Paho. I am working with it. But why does it stops the service when you kill the app? Is this solved in some versions of it or it is still the same? Ravi, you could answer as well. :D

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić I have no problems with this stopping the service. My Mqtt-Service is running all the time. I had some issues with reconnecting and i used the methods above for solving this.

Comment: @kdoteu Your service is not stopped when you swipe away the app from recent apps? These two questions describe the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543569/paho-mqtt-android-service-issue and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142000/paho-mqtt-android-service-wake-up-activity

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić No the service do not stop. I thinks its because I added ‹service android:name="com.ibm.android.service.MqttService" /› to my Manifest.

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić do you use .unregisterResource() or something else? I only use this method, when I lost the connection and want to reconnect. If you use this method in onDestroy(), thats why you did not get notified from the service.

Comment: @kdoteu Would you mind sharing your mqtt code, I am also experiencing the service stopping when swiping away the app.

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić I can see the pings on broker. Can you please share your code or tell exactly what you are doing. This seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: @Ravi Unfortunately, I have left this project before some time. :/

Comment: What about if my mqtt client is running on a background service? Should I bind these methods to the services life cycle?

Comment: Using Android service 1.1.1 with mqttv3 1.2.1, reconnect works when setAutomaticReconnect is set to true, but re-subscribing is required even clean session is set to false.