# Reconnect MQTT client in android

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

I am using mqtt paho library in my android app. It works properly until mqtt client lost connection due to network problem. Do I need to connect client manually or it has some mechanism to connect automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to register resources so that mqtt library can handle mqtt client reconnect by itself when network reconnect happens. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546973/reconnecting-from-airplane-mode-with-mqtt-android-service), it should help.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am using MqttAsyncClient  and it do not have registerResources.

Comment: you should be using Android Service jar rather than Java Client from paho for Android, else you will have to build few more functionalities over Java client which is already built in service jar.

Comment: The issue has been solved by using broadcastreceiver for network change and by using connectionLost callback.